# scrapy, unable to locate a text phase in website

Tags: python, parsing, scrapy

I am trying to extract the text

**60 Days** from website A
https://www.vitalsource.com/products/abnormal-psychology-susan-nolen-hoeksema-v9781259765667

**Lifetime Access** from website B
https://www.vitalsource.com/products/teaming-with-nutrients-jeff-lowenfels-v9781604695175

I tried to use abs xpath, both return nothing.

for A

```
//div[2]/div[1]/label[1]
```

for B

```
//div[1]/span[1]/label[1]
```

nor css path

```
.u-weight--bold.type--magic9.u-inline
```

I believe the texts I want to extract are not generated by javascript. so I don't know anything else I can do to solve this problem.

Please assist!

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you need is rendered by Javascript, but it's also available in JSON format inside the page. All you need to do is to select the element that contains the data, parse the data using JSON lib and access the desired field.

[image]

```
import json
import pprint

data = response.xpath(
    '//div[@data-react-class="vs.CurrentRegionOnlyWarningModal"]'
    '/@data-react-props')
.extract_first()

json_data = json.loads(data)

pprint.pprint(json_data)
{'selectedVariant': None,
 'variants': [{'asset_id': 88677112,
               'created_at': '2016-10-07T14:17:10.000Z',
               'deleted_at': None,
               'distributable': True,
               'downloadable_duration': 'perpetual',
               'full_base_currency': 'USD',
               'full_base_price': '107.5',
               'full_currency': 'USD',
               'full_price': '107.5',
               'full_price_converted': False,
               'id': 476831514,
               'import_id': 'a3b99a3de0df7d0442253798cba8b8ea',
               'in_store': True,
               'item_type': 'Single',
               ....
               'online_duration': '60 days',
```

So, you can access it normally:

```
for x in json_data['variants']:
    print(x['online_duration'])
```

It's important to note that this site has some variants for each product, and there are more fields with this same string. You have to understand how this site organize the products to get the right data, but this approach should be enough to access all information you need.

Answer (score 0):

It is generated by javascript, unfortunately. So you would need to use something like `selenium` for this most likely.

Comment: ahh I thought all the script crated data are inside <script> block

Comment: @CongLuo yea sometimes you can find the information there but usually, it's all generated by the browser